# java.lang.String cannot be cast to system.Object

Tags: java, string, classcastexception, jni4net

I have used JNI4NET framework to invoke .Net code from Java.
JNI4NET has generated proxy class for .Net code. One of the methods accept system.Object as an input parameter.

I want to send String value as input to that method. I have wrote the below code for that-

```
        String s = "test";
        Object b = s;
        system.Object object = (system.Object) b;
```

And passing this obj as an input to proxy method. The above code throws runtime exception java.lang.String cannot be cast to system.Object. Any help or pointers will be useful.

Comment: what is `system.Object` anyway?

Comment: .Net uses system.Object as compared to java.lang.Object in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.String` can be cast to `java.lang.Object` (though there's no reason to cast it - you can simply assign it to an `Object` reference as you do in - `Object b = s;`), not to `system.Object`.

I did some searching. It looks like this might help :

```
String s = "test";
system.String b = new system.String(s);
system.Object object = b;
```

Since [system.String](http://jni4net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jni4net.j/src/main/java/system/String.java) is a sub-class of [system.Object](http://jni4net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jni4net.j/src/main/java/system/Object.java), you can pass it to your `test` method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Eran. In this case, how can pass a String value to system.Object parameter ?

Comment: @Sanjay What is `system.Object`? Is it a class you created? What constructors does it have?

Comment: Its a .Net equivalent method created by JNI4NET framework in Java. Below is the syntax-

    public native boolean test(java.lang.String AVariableFullName, system.Object Value);

Comment: Second parameter of this native method accepts only system.Object value. I want to pass String value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eran. This looks closure to the solution. However I am getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to system.String When trying to pass String value while creating system.String

Comment: Eran, still getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to system.String, while creating system.String

Comment: I tried the below code-   system.String b = new String(s);
   system.Object object = b;
   return tracer.WriteVariable(variableName, object);

Comment: shouldn't it be `system.String b = new system.String(s);`?

Comment: yes that works. But it gives runtime exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.Convert(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Comment: The above solution allow me to pass String value at compile, it throws runtime exception :-(

Comment: @Sanjay Perhaps you are missing some jar in your library path when you run the code.